# Comapring two dictionary values with keys which are in list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
group1=  [ {
              'Name': 'C21114',
              'Description': '',
              'num': '12321114',
              'working': 'true',
              'belongs': 'Default',
              'Expiry_Date': '',
              '\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID': 'C21114',
              'Password': '*SECRET*',
          },
          {
              'Name': 'Mahes',
              'Description': '',
              'num': '1026',
              'working': 'true',
              'belongs': 'Default',
              'Expiry_Date': '',
              '\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID': 'Mahi',
              'Password': '*SECRET*',
          },
          {
              'Name': 'pri',
              'Description': '',
              'num': '1027',
              'working': 'true',
              'belongs': 'Default',
              'Expiry_Date': '',
              '\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID': 'priya',
              'Password': '*SECRET*',
          }]
group2=   [{
              'Name': 'C21114',
              'Description': '',
              'num': '12321114',
              'working': 'true',
              'belongs': 'Default',
              'Expiry_Date': '',
              'User_ID': 'C21114',
              'Password': '*SECRET*',
          },
          {
              'Name': 'Mahes',
              'Description': '',
              'num': '1026',
              'working': 'true',
              'belongs': 'Default',
              'Expiry_Date': '',
              'User_ID': 'Mahi',
              'Password': '*SECRET*',
          },
          {
              'Name': 'pri',
              'Description': '',
              'num': '1027',
              'working': 'true',
              'belongs': 'Default',
              'Expiry_Date': '',
              'User_ID': 'priya',
              'Password': '*SECRET*',
          }]
```

Need to compare few keys of group1 and group2 are same or not. group1 and group2  are list in that many dictionaries.I just need to compare few keys with its values between group1 and group2.Explained with one example.Example : keys_to_compare = {'name', 'num',working} from group1 and group2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're post is likely to get more responses if you post your attempts

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need it to do

```
key_to_compare = ['Name', 'num', 'working']
for key in key_to_compare:
    for d1 in group1:
        for d2 in group2:
            if d1[key] == d2[key]:
                print "same values for %s %s %s" % (key, d1[key], d2[key])
```

Change the if statement to do what you would like for elements with the same value.

Comment: Thank you, used this to complete my thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make an assumption on what the output you wanted.  I created a list of lists.  The inner most list is a part of indexs (group1 then group2) of matches.  This is the code:

```
keys_to_compare = ['Name','num','working']
matches = []
for idx1 in range(len(group1)):
    ref1 = group1[idx1]
    found = False
    for idx2 in range(len(group2)):
        ref2 = group2[idx2]
        found = True
        for key in keys_to_compare:
            if ref1[key] != ref2[key]:
                found = False
        if found:
            matches.append([idx1,idx2])
            break
    if found: continue
print 'matches=%r' % (matches)
```

The result:

```
matches=[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented as a function, this should give you what you want:

```
def compare(key):
    g1 = []
    g2 = []
    for i in group1:
        g1.append(i[key])
    for j in group2:
        g2.append(j[key])
    return g1 == g2
```

Put in the key name, then it will return True if the values are same in both groups and False if not. For instance, to check the keys in your list, you'll do:

```
keys_to_compare = ['Name','num','working']

for x in keys_to_compare:
    print compare(x)
```